# Trouble with chrome.extension.sendRequest();

Tags: google-chrome

***contenescript.js***

```
var someText = 'some text to show1';
chrome.extension.sendRequest({'action' : 'openMyTab','text': someText});
```

***background.html***

```
function onRequest(request, sender, callback) {
        if (request.action == 'openMyTab') {
    alert(" Inside onRequest with  " + request.text);
        }
      };

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
```

This works fine. And as expected gives an alert message.

But on changing the ***contentscript.js*** to something like this.

```
Wordlistonilne.Selector.dblClick = function(){
  var st = Wordlistonilne.Selector.getSelected();
  if(st!=''){
 myMethod('openMyTab',st);
  }
}


function myMethod(action,message){
 alert("myMethod : action = " + action + "message = " + message);
 chrome.extension.sendRequest({'action' : action,'text': message});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).bind("dblclick", Wordlistonilne.Selector.dblClick);
});
```

I get the alert with the action and message. But the chrome.extension.sendRequest doesnt seem to work.

F1 F1 please help me out

Comment: Did you try debugging? Chrome has an excellent js debugger, with breakpoints and everything. After you load your unpacked extensions, just click the active view *or* just set a breakpoint in your content script.